# What is the best practice for accommodating both a one-to-many and a one-to-all (or one-to-*) relationship?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

Just curious what is the best practice for solving the following issue.   I have institutions, accounts and users tables.    Institutions and accounts have a one-to-many relationship.  Institutions and users have a one-to-many relationship.  Users and accounts have a many-to-many relationship or alternatively they could have a many-to-all (or *) accounts.   Meaning, that a user could be designated to all accounts, and any new accounts that are added to the institution the user would have access to without explicitly adding the relationship.

Comment: Can a user have access to (be associated with) the accounts of more than one institution?  If Yes, would a "super-user" have access to all the accounts of one institution, all the accounts of a set of institutions, or all the accounts of all institutions?  (If no, then we'll want to factor in restrictions on account assignments.)

Comment: No, a user cannot be associated with more than one institution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like so:

```
Institutions
    InstitutionID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    Name VARCHAR(255)

Users
    UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    Username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    InstitutionID INT NOT NULL

Accounts
    AccountID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    Account VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    InstitutionID INT NOT NULL

Users_Accounts
    Users_AccountsID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    UserID INT NOT NULL
    AccountID INT NULL
```

Have a UserID w/ a `NULL` entry in the `Users_Accounts` table have global (*) access. This way, you can determine the Institution on any Account and/or User, as well as their permissions.

Edit: Columns w/ the same name in different tables imply a Foreign Key. Please use them if you aren't doing heavy loads.

Answer (score 1):

Make `Accounts` have a foreign key to `Institutions`.

Make `Users` have a foreign key to `Institutions`.

Make a flag on the `Users` account that indicates that they will have access to all `Accounts` on that `Institution`.

Create a many-to-many mapping table for `Users` to `Accounts`.  This will be used only if the `User` does not have their flag set such that they have access to all `Accounts` on the `Institution`.

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mapping table for many-to-many relationships.  If a user has many accounts, create a users_to_account mapping table with two columns, one with the account foreign key, and one with users foreign key, and I would even make them together a composite primary key:

```
users           account
-----           ----------
1               5
1               10
2               5
2               10
```

So, accounts 5 and 10 both map to users 1 and 2.

Comment: Yeah, Eric, I'm not sure.  I'm a little cloudy today, recovering from a cold.

Comment: Why would you use a lookup table (and another join!) when you can just put a FK on the Account table? No sense in a lookup for a one-to-many relationship, just standard 3NF. Also, you haven't addressed the many-to-many aspect. Therefore, I went with a -1.

Comment: I updated my answer to address many-to-many.  As you stated, in a one-to-many, skip the mapping table and just put a FK in the "one" table (i.e. account table)